# JUnit covering unreachable code

Tags: code-coverage, junit4, unreachable-statement

I am given with a java code and i have to write test cases so that 100% coverage can be obtained. But, the code given is written in such a way that one of the "if" statement will never be true. We cannot change the code, still we have to achieve 100% code coverage. How to do that. The tool is only helper, its mentioned in one of the post, but what if anyhow we need to do that.The code is-`

```
    public double getArea(int side1, int side2, int side3 ) {
    String type = determineTriangleType(side1+"", side2+".1", side3+"");
    double  area;

    //Different way of calculation for Equilateral
    if(type.equals("Equilateral"))
    {
        area =(Math.sqrt(3)/4)*side1 *side2;
    }`  else{.....}
```

I am not able to give the test case for which above "if" is true.

The determineTriangleType method is`public String determineTriangleType(String side1, String side2, String side3 ) {......Some Processing.....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach here is to make sure `type` is the desired value. To do that you would need to change `determineTriangleType` to return the required type.

This is where mock objects come in. The idea is to extend the Java class under test and override `determineTriangleType` to return the right value unconditionally in your derived implementation. Then you call the method you want to test on a instance of the derived class, and now the method's if statement will execute.

```
public class DerivedToCheckIf extends BaseClass {
  @Override
  public String determineTriangleType(String side1, String side2, String side3) {
    // call to super implementation may not be required
    // if the method does not change object state which affects the method under test
    super.determineTriangleType(side1, side2, side3);
    return "Equilateral";
  }
}
```

Comment: But still, percentage of coverage in original base class will not change as that statement is still unreachable in base class

Comment: Well, the alternative is to hope that `determineTriangleType` has a bug which *cancels* the bug in the method under test. In that case you can pass in an equilateral triangle and get expected results anyway.